# How to backup a chainlink node?

Tags: chainlink, ubuntu

My node is v1.1.0 with remote database.
I don't know what files I should back up (besides the database which is remote and under hopefully proper backup management) to ensure I can restore my nodes after catastrophes - specifically does the ~./chainlink directory contain keys used by the node?

Answer (score 0):

You can find backup best practices below, to answer your question directly,

> By default, the Chainlink node does not contain any critical data
> other than the logs found in the Chainlink directory.

Databases
https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/#database-automatic-backups

The Nodes
https://docs.chain.link/docs/best-practices-aws/#ec2-instance-backup

Comment: thanks but its not clear that this is the correct answer - specifically does this answer the question for nodes built from source?

Comment: also youve replied with the aws doc answer but that default would be arch / platform specific so further clarification sought here thanks.